# Angle between two vectors in a Minkowski (Finsler) space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, finsler-geometry

Given a Minkowski (or Finsler) space $(V,F)$, I am wondering how to define the angle between two vectors $w$ and $v$. I first thought it must be as $$\cos\theta(w,v)=\frac{g_w(w,v)}{\sqrt{g_w(w,w)g_w(v,v)}}.$$ Indeed I fixed the inner product $g_w$ and then defined the angle using it. I am also suspected that one can define the angle as $$\cos\theta(w,v)=\frac{g_w(w,v)}{F(v)F(w)}.$$

Any idea?

P.S. by $g_w$ I mean the second fundamental form which is defined as $$g_w(v,u)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 F^2}{\partial t \partial s}(w+su+tv)|_{s=t=0}.$$

Comment: I doubt that you need angle in Finsler space. If you insist, then look at Riemannian case, choose the most important property of angle and use it as the definition --- typically different properties lead to different definitions. The one you propose looks okey, it is not symmetric, but you always have to sacrifice something in the Finsler world.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin I need the angle in the case of Finsler since I am trying to show that the angle between two special vectors remain constant along a submanifold. Could you please give me some reference where the angle in Riamannian is defined. You mentioned that the one that I defined looks OK. Which one? I have defined two.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin You mentioned that different properties lead to different definitions. Is there any property which leads to my second definition?

Comment: I agree with @AntonPetrunin.  Following Busemann, I would also say:  do you need vectors?  Perhaps define the angle at $p$ between curves $a$ and $b$ as $2 \lim \arcsin d(a_s, b_s)/2s$, where $a_s$ and $b_s$ are the points at distance $s$ from $p$ along the curves.

Comment: @Majid, is not it the first variation formula if you move in the direction $v$ and measure the distances to a point in the direction $w$?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin if you are talking about my case, no. If you are talking about some definition of angle, I do not know. My problem is that I saw through some examples that the angle between two special vector fields is constant along a submanifold. I am suspected that it is true is general case of my problem and so I needed to define the angle.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin what do you mean by the most important property of angle and use it as the definition?
The only thing that I know is that the angle is the cos^-1 or sin^-1 of the inner product or exterior product divided by the norms!

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Is there any reference that I can refer to?